# Laravel unable to pass variable to view

Tags: laravel-4

I have the following code in my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('org', function()
{
    $org = Org::all();
    return View::make('org.index')
        ->with('org', $org)
        ->with('category', 'Org');
});
```

When I visit /org in my application I receive the following error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: category (View: /var/www/html/.../app/views/org/index.blade.php)
```

I have the following code in my index.blade.php file:

```
@if($category == 'Org')
    @foreach($org as $organization)
     ...
    @endforeach
@endif
```

If I remove the if statement (which references the $category variable) everything works just fine.

Why is `$category` not defined in the view?

**EDIT:**

This is rather embarrassing, but I'm going to describe the problem in case someone else finds it useful.

I have a lot of comments and duplicate code in my routes.php file as this is my first time using Laravel and I'm testing things out. It turns out I had a duplicate of the above route (though closer to the bottom of the routes.php file) which did not pass the $category variable to the view. I removed it and this solved my problem.

I was under the impression that if there were duplicate routes, the one described first would be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather embarrassing, but I'm going to describe the problem in case someone else finds it useful.

I have a lot of comments and duplicate code in my routes.php file as this is my first time using Laravel and I'm testing things out. It turns out I had a duplicate of the above route (though closer to the bottom of the routes.php file) which did not pass the $category variable to the view. I removed it and this solved my problem.

I was under the impression that if there were duplicate routes, the one described first would be used.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Session::get('category')
```

if you have more than one variables to pass to view, you can use the following approaches:

```
Route::get('org', function()
{
    $org = Org::all();
    $category = 'Org';
    return View::make('org.index', compact('org', 'category'));
});
```

**or**

```
Route::get('org', function()
{
    $data = [];

    $data['org'] = Org::all();
    $data['category'] = 'Org';
    return View::make('org.index', $data);
});
```